# Displaying all images in a directory with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to display all the images that have been resized in a view. It is only showing one image though, although there are more than just one image in the directory. Here is my code:

```
namespace Application\Model;

class Images 
{
    /**
     * Gets the files from the specified directory
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getFilesFromDir()
    {
        $iterator = new \DirectoryIterator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test_image/');

        $holder = array();

        foreach ($iterator as $finfo) {
            if ($finfo->isFile()) {
                $holder[$finfo->getPath()] = $finfo->getFilename();
            }
        }

        return $holder;
    }


    /**
     * Resizes images in a directory
     */
    public static function resizeImages() 
    {
        $percent = 0.5; // scales the image to half its original size


        foreach (self::getFilesFromDir() as $key => $value) {
            $img_size = getimagesize($key . '/' . $value);

            // get the original height and width of the image
            $o_width = $img_size[0];
            $o_height = $img_size[1];

            // set the new width
            $new_width = 500; // 500 pixels, can changed if need be

            if ($o_width != $new_width) {
                $new_height_calc = $new_width / $o_width;

                $new_height = $new_height_calc * $o_height;

                // now create the resized image
                $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($key . '/' . $value);

                imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $o_width, $o_height);

                imagejpeg($new_image, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test_image/resized_images/' . $value, 100);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * gets the resized images located in resized images directory
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getResizedImages()
    {
        $iterator = new \DirectoryIterator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test_image/resized_images/');

        $holder = array();

        foreach ($iterator as $finfo) {
            if ($finfo->isFile()) {
                $holder[] = $finfo->getFilename();
            }
        }

        return $holder;
    }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {
    Images::resizeImages();

    $images = function() {
        foreach (Images::getResizedImages() as $value) {
            $img[] = $value;
        }

        return array_values($img);
    };

    return new ViewModel(array('images' => $images()));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the resized images valid files? IsFile only returns on following conditions; Returns TRUE if the file exists and is a regular file (not a link or dir), otherwise FALSE

Comment: yes, they are .jpeg files, but only one image shows up on the page (there are two in the test_image directory, so I am a little unsure why both are not resized and placed in the resized_images directory.

Comment: Based on your updated post, are you overwriting your array key?  `$holder[$finfo->getPath()]` on `getFilesFromDir`

Comment: here is an image if it helps: http://imgur.com/Qb729w6

Comment: wouldn't it still be the same path? it is calling the directory set in $iterator

Comment: Path would be the same but the array value on its key gets overwritten, so basicly you keep having a single array key, becaus its key is kept the same. To make it unique you could do something like `$holder[$finfo->getPath()][] = $finfo->getFilename();` this way you have a multidimensional array containing several files for each directory

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity;

Inside loop on `getFilesFromDir()` method, you're resetting your array value because its key/index is not unique.
Instead of `$holder[$finfo->getPath()] = $finfo->getFilename();` use  `$holder[$finfo->getPath()][] = $finfo->getFilename();` to create an multidimensional array.
The result will be an array where first key contains the path, followed by an array of files.